# TypeORM connection without explicitly specifying database

Tags: node.js, typescript, typeorm

I wonder if it is somehow possible using TypeOrm to connect to a database server without having to specify a schema.

With the normal mysql module in Node it would work like this:

```
const connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password:"xxx"
});
```

However, a database must be specified in the connection options in TypeOrm, if this is an empty string or does not exist, an error occurs.

So I don't see any possibility to connect to the server with TypeOrm and create a new schema with this connection.

Do I have to use the normal mysql module or is there a possibility with TypeORM that I am not aware of?